# A/C not cold on highway

Tags: ac, scion, refrigerant, r134a

Ac not blowing cold when driving on highway. 2006 scion XA with a fresh r134a recharge. Ac blows cold idling and around town, but when driving on highway (>50mph) ac blows totally warm. Cools down within 1 minute after slowing down. Any thoughts?

I just put it on a set of manifold gauges. I checked the pressures at idle and when revving high for a few minutes to simulate highway driving when the problem occurs.

Starting pressures

- (idle) 35psi (L) 200psi (H)
- Max pressures (when revving to ~3k rpm for ~2min) 62psi (L) 245psi (H)
- Min pressures (when revving to ~3k rpm for ~2min) 23psi (L) 165psi (H)

These are slightly higher than the manufacturer spec I pulled from the shop manual I have.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you have your high-side/low-side pressures checked?  That will usually help identify the cause.  Could be low refrigerant, clogged orifice, or just about anything else at this point.

Comment: I just put it on a set of manifold gauges. I checked the pressures at idle and when revving high for a few minutes to simulate highway driving when the problem occurs. 

Starting pressures (idle)
35psi (L)
200psi (H)

Max pressures (when revving to ~3k rpm for ~2min)
62psi (L)
245psi (H)

Min pressures (when revving to ~3k rpm for ~2min)

23psi (L)
165psi (H) these are slightly higher than the manufacturer spec I pulled from the shop manual I have.

Comment: Do you know the exact amount of r134a in your system? Second guessing can be either too much or not enough. Idle rpm pressures mean nothing; do you drive at idle when using ac? If using service manuals then there should be specs to follow when measuring low/high side pressures relative to engine rpm.  Some models can be measured at idle while one model specifies 2k rpm. Under most operating conditions for r134a, low side should remain between 28-35 psi, corresponding to evap temps around 35F-42F regardless of rpm. High side will vary in proportion to engine rpm and shouldn't exceed 300 psi.

Comment: Initially 0.98lb. I checked the sticker under the hood and the max R134A fill is listed as 0.90lb so I had the shop discharge it to 0.90lb and retested the pressures.

In the retest I noticed some differences in pressures.

Idle 35/185PSI L/H
3krpm 25/255PSI L/H

In the first test with .98lb the pressure rose on the high side then crashed to 165 and the low side fell to 23psi then rose to 62 as the high side fell which roughly corresponded to when the AC gave out.

In the second test the pressures held constant and the AC didn't give out, but it still gives out on highway.

Comment: When I drive on the highway for >2 miles the ac still gives out with 0.90lb r134a. I tried revving to 4k rpm when parked and the ac also gives out then too but I haven't put the manifold gauges on that yet.

Shop manual states to test at 1.5k rpm so here are those pressures 26/225PSI L/H



No frost on the ac lines, no bubbles in the ac viewer window, no belt squeal, and the condenser fan is spinning.

Could the system still be slightly over pressure?

Comment: Use service manuals in ac repairs, especially when specific rpm is given. As you see, pressures are appropriate relative to humidity as humidity affects both pressures. When you say "gives out" this may mean the engine computer detects over revving or wide open throttle where it will disable the compressor for a momentary perfomance gain. As revs drop back, the ecm will enable compressor operation. Similar to passing a vehicle or flat footing in stop light racing; wide open throttle is detected to disable ac until throttle is reduced then ac is re-enabled. What's vent temps, outside temps.